# How to fix Django Rest API error?

Tags: python, django, opencv, django-views, django-rest-framework

How to fix this error?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/HP/Downloads/cv_api/cv_api/manage.py", line 10, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>
> File "F:\Anaconda2Installation\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>
> File "F:\Anaconda2Installation\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg\django\core\management__init__.py", line 316, in execute
>       settings.INSTALLED_APPS
>
> File "F:\Anaconda2Installation\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg\django\conf__init__.py", line 53, in **getattr**
>       self._setup(name)
>
> File "F:\Anaconda2Installation\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg\django\conf__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
>       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
>
> File "F:\Anaconda2Installation\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.5-py2.7.egg\django\conf__init__.py", line 97, in **init**
>       mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
>
> File "F:\Anaconda2Installation\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>
> **import**(name)
>
> ImportError: No module named cv_api.settings

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `settings.py` file to the `cv_api` directory.